# error Access is denied when installing programs with windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I get a error "access is denied" while trying to install software

I have tried

- disable UAC
- Disable anti-virus software
- make the file temp under my control
- run as admin

the only thing that worked was creating a new user but before I ditch my old one I want to see if I can find a way to keep it.

But I can't find a way to stop it from saying "accses denied". Nothing works except creating a new user.

Comment: You could try using ProcMon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor both the installation process as well as any Windows Installer processes launched during the install, to see where they are trying to access and in what way (read, write) and verify that you have the relevant permissions.

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but did you reboot after making any of those changes? Windows is silly about that sometimes and requires a reboot to take effect some of those. If you're an admin, then there's obviously another issue. Did it ever work before?

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking the install file and running it as administrator. If you don't see that option then your account must not have admin privileges.